# Xamarin Forms - Images fetching from URL is not displaying in Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019, imagesource

I'm trying to **fetch** an image from the URL for my Xamarin Forms project.

```
<ci:CircleImage Source="{Binding displayPicture}" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  Aspect="AspectFill" BorderColor="#5bb6e7" BorderThickness="2"/>
```

Previously i was working on Visual studio 2017 V15.9.30. It simply **shows the image** from URL.
Even in iOS, it is working fine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1NX9.png)(Visual Studio 2017)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSwl8.png)(iOS)

Currently, i have updated to visual studio 2019 v16.8.5. But here image is **not getting displayed**.
Same code is running on both the versions but can't get the image in Visual Studio 2019.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c3g4.png)(Visual studio 2019)

I've tried all possible solutions but it isn't working yet. Can someone help me out with this, please?

***Points i have tried :***

1. Image source URL is HTTPS.
2. HttpClient Implementation is **Managed**
3. SSL/TLS Implementation is **Native TLS 1.2+**
4. In Manifest file i have added **android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"**
5. Tried using **ImageSourceConverter**. But not able to include the library System.Net.WebCient

Comment: Did you use same xamarin.forms version on both Visual studio versions?

Comment: I tested the on Visual Studio16.4.3. The `CircleImage` could load the image from uri directly. Could you provide the https link or a code snippet to help us reproduce?

Comment: @Wendy Zang - MSFT

`<ci:CircleImage Source="https://picsum.photos/200" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  Aspect="AspectFill" BorderColor="#5bb6e7" BorderThickness="2"/>` 


This is the sample URL used. While view it from the browser, it displays the image. But in output, it shows nothing.. Blank white space is displayed at the place of circle image.

Comment: @Argon Yes **same versions** on both visual Studio

Comment: @PrasanthKumar I loaded the same https image link with yours. It works well on my device. Check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/undefined

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT That is the issue. I am also able to view the Image in my visual studio 17. But in VS 2019 only, i am not able to view it.

Comment: @PrasanthKumar What is the version for your VS? Have you checked the network?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I am using VS 2019 v16.8.5. No problem in internet connection.

Comment: Try the image link provide by the CircleImage NuGet.  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/Tamarin_portrait.JPG I would keep on testing.

Comment: And try to use the Image control to load the uri instead of the CircleImage to check the source link.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Tried using Image Control with source URL you provided, Same issue still occurs

Comment: @PrasanthKumar I guess maybe there is something wrong with your VS. You could try to repair it and test again.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Repaired and updated VS 2019. But that doesn't help.

Comment: @PrasanthKumar It is so stange. Have you tried to test on another PC and device?